# Why are the custom errors displaying for the wrong dates?

Tags: php, yii

Errors are displaying for the wrong dates. The model(BookingRoom) is running this custom rule on start and end dates on a tabular input form to check for overlapping date ranges. What could I be doing wrong?

```
public function notOverlap()
{                      
    $startDateThis = new DateTime($this->startDate);                        
    $endDateThis = new DateTime($this->endDate); 
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->condition = "(id !='".$this->id."' AND bookingId ='".$this->bookingId."')";

    $items = BookingRoom::model()->findAll($criteria);



            foreach ($items as $item){                    

                $startDateItem = new DateTime($item->startDate);                    
                $endDateItem = new DateTime($item->endDate);                    


                   if ($startDateItem <= $endDateThis && $startDateThis <= $endDateItem)             
                      {                
                        $this->addError('startDate', 'Room already taken!');
                        $this->addError('endDate', 'Room already taken!');
                      }                    
            } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the time variables contain the correct info before you do the comparison?

Comment: I've just been wondering if I need to use Javascript validation now because it is all server-side validation

Comment: Javascript/jQuery validation provides quick response, elevating the user experience. Server-side validation provides security.